# Javascript popUp cfmail in Python

Tags: javascript, python, coldfusion

Using BeautifulSoup I extracted email links from a page.  I am interested in how you could send an email to links that produce a pop up email form.

More simply put:
Is is it *possible* to send an email to the an address with only this data?

```
href = javascript:popUp('cfmail.cfm?LName=LastName&FName=FirstName')
```

Or if I follow the link in code is it possible to fill out the email form that it generates?

Thank you

Comment: Wow, first 5 seconds after reading the title `Javascript popUp cfmail in Python` my mind was blown.

Comment: Instead of trying to be smart ass you'd better try to learn something, for example how to ask questions. It'd help.

Comment: I got the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to extract an email with that information alone, unless you have access to the server and correct values for the variables `LastName` and `FirstName`. The line `cfmail.cfm?LName=LastName&FName=FirstName` is getting a user's email from the site's server, presumably after the user is logged in.

Comment: That sort of popup will generally alert the user and then say something like "Is _________ the best email to send you really cool news about our products too?" or something.